# sp2013 master - the base type is not allowed for this page not registered as safe

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, parser-error

I uploaded new master page via SharePoint UI  and go this parse error:
rolling back to an older version get me same error.
the name of the master is nameNewMaster.master

seems like an missing key or something like that.
tnx

EDIT: 
I reset the master to site definition which gave the ability to keep working .
but I don't know if I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you deploy a master page through a wsp. Deployed master pages are "ghosted" and will get updated automatically throughout the farm when the wsp is updated. But if the master page is then manually edited in the gallery, this will "unghost" it. The solution is to re-ghost it.

Explanation and powershell fix here: http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2012/07/revert-customized-maste-pages-back-to-ghosted-state-in-sharepoint-2010/

Steps to fix through Site Settings here: http://anoojnair.com/2017/06/master-page-issue-the-base-type-is-not-allowed-for-this-page-the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe/